# Using google analytics to track hits on an XML web service

Tags: xml, web-services, google-analytics

I have a xml web service which I would like to track using Google Analytics.  Since it uses a small client side javascript to do the tracking, this is a problem.  Is it possible to workaround this without running a javascript client server side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this would be of help

[Server Side Google Analytics (PHP)](http://code.google.com/p/serversidegoogleanalytics/)

Answer (score 1):

Work around? Of course, this is the web. Hook up an HTTP analyzer and see what that Google JavaScript transmits. Then, have your webservice make those same HTTP requests.

But wouldn't it be easier to just store that data in a database?

Comment: Well we actually thought about writing our own tracking statistics, but all of our websites are currently on GA, and we have already built a number of tools for looking at the data, so I figured I would ask before I go about planning  out something that might have already existed.