# Appending GA event tracking to JSON element

Tags: php, json, events, google-analytics, server-side

I am trying to add event tracking to a product that is being translated to html cross-domain...

The file is located server-side and written in PHP. The JSON snippet that I need to append the GA event to is as follows:

```
"products": [
    {
        "title": "product",
        "description": "description",
        "thumbnail": "http://myurl.com/picture.jpg",
        "price": "&pound;1.99",
        "url": "http://link.com"
    },]
```

Now, reading up a little bit on this on this article has given me a bit of insight: [Using google analytics to track hits on an XML web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449866/using-google-analytics-to-track-hits-on-an-xml-web-service?rq=1)

Would it be a matter of something as simple as this?

```
<?php
//Initilize GA Tracker
$tracker = new GoogleAnalytics\Tracker('UA-12345678-9', 'example.com');
?>

"products": [
        {
            "title": "product",
            "description": "description",
            "thumbnail": "http://myurl.com/picture.jpg",
            "price": "&pound;1.99",
            "url": "http://link.com"
        },$ga->setEvent("Category", "Action", "Label", "Value");]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, look at mit Github Project

https://github.com/ins0/google-measurement-php-client

it is a PHP client library to communicate with Google Analytics from server-side.
otherwise you can use other great repositorys, look here

https://github.com/search?q=google-measurement&source=cc

Comment: 'Sure', as in it would work?! The site that this JSON is fed into would be running GA in a <head> somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your response @ins0
I'll get back to you tomorrow when I can see it come through into analytics. 
The whole purpose was really to ask if the syntax works as I am essentially putting php into the JSON in my example above.